# Pass wildcard to scp in a wrapper bash script

Tags: bash, scp, wildcard-expansion

I am writing a bash wrapper for scp'ing into and from a certain host with a certain username, like:

```
johny@bonjour:~/bin$ cat scpphcl 
#!/bin/bash

download=false
upload=false
local=""
remote=""

usage()
{
    echo "Usage: $0 -d[-u] -l <LocalPath> -r <RemotePath>"
    exit 1
}

while getopts "h?dul:r:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    h|\?)
        usage
        ;;
    d)
        download=true
        upload=false
        ;;
    u)
        download=false
        upload=true
        ;;
    l)
        local=$OPTARG
        ;;
    r)
        remote=$OPTARG
        ;;
    esac
done

if [[ -z $local || -z $remote ]]; then
    echo "Need to provide local and remote path."
    usage
fi

if $download; then
    scp somebody@somehost:"$remote" $local
elif $upload; then
    scp $local somebody@somehost:"$remote"
else
    echo "Neither download nor upload?"
    exit 1
fi

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Something wrong happened in the scp process."
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

It works well with the usual filenames, but if there is any wildcard in the local filename field, it will not work right.

```
johny@bonjour:~/test$ scpphcl -u -l * -r /u/somebody/temp
Need to provide local and remote path.
Usage: /Users/johny/bin/scpphcl -d[-u] -l <LocalPath> -r <RemotePath>
```

There is a walkaround, using sinqle quotes around the local file argument if there is a wildcard in it:

```
johny@bonjour:~/test$ scpphcl -u -l '*' -r /u/somebody/temp
```

But even this walkaround will not work, if the command is issued outside the folder `test`:

```
johny@bonjour:~/test$ cd ..
johny@bonjour:~$ scpphcl -u -l 'test/*' -r /u/somebody/temp
```

This doesn't work and will hang in the scp process.

Any help in how to pass the wildcard in local filenames with the bash wrapper?

Comment: You might need to escape the wild-card to let it be expanded remotely and _not_ locally

Comment: @Inian Neither `scpphcl -u -l 'test/\*' -r /u/somebody/temp` nor `scpphcl -u -l test/\* -r /u/somebody/temp` works.

Comment: You'll need to quote `"$OPTARG"` (thus), too.  And `"$local"`, and `"$remote"`.  Just quote properly, everywhere.  Actually, you want `local=($OPTARG)`, and then use `"${local[@]}"` in the command.  But call it something else - `local` is a Bash keyword.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thank you very much, Toby. It works. Also, thanks for your suggestion of giving the local path a name other than `local`. I didn't know it is a bash keyword. Could you put your comment into the answer section so that I can mark it as the solution? It would be better if you add some explanation. I guess `localfile=($OPTARG)` probably treat the wildcard expansion as an array. Later, when it was used in the `scp` command, is `${localfile[@]}` the way to dereference the array?

Comment: Yes, that's an array.  The way to expand the array is `"${localfile[@]}"` (those double-quotes are important!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best not to require your users to quote wildcard patterns.  I'd instead change the interface of your program to accept *any number* of local paths, after the option arguments:

```
echo "Usage: $0 [-d|-u] [-r <RemotePath>] <LocalPath>..."
```

When reading options, consume them with `shift`:

```
while getopts "h?dur:" opt; do
    case "$opt" in
    h|\?)
        usage
        exit 0
        ;;
    d)
        download=true
        upload=false
        ;;
    u)
        download=false
        upload=true
        ;;
    r)
        remote="$OPTARG"
        ;;
    *)
        usage >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
```

Now the remaining positional arguments are the local filenames (and can be accessed with `"$@"` - note the all-important double-quotes there):

```
if test -z "$*"  # no LocalPath arguments!
then usage >&2; exit 1
elif $download
then exec scp somebody@somehost:"$remote" "$@"
elif $upload
then exec scp "$@" somebody@somehost:"$remote"
fi
```

Comment: Perfect solution! More concise and more user-friendly! Thanks a bunch, Toby!

Comment: Another question: what's the gain of using `exec` to do the `scp`, instead of calling it directly as I did before?

Comment: It saves a fork - but does mean that you don't get to do anything afterwards (so your helpful "something went wrong" message doesn't get shown - I'm hardy enough that `scp`'s own error message is enough, but your users might differ there).  Another advantage is that when the exit status matters, your users get that status directly (rather than just `0` or `1` as in your version - you'd have to do some work to preserve the status code).